# Uncaught Reference Error: ShowTable is not defined . But i have already made that function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically generating link through java script with this code

```
  var infoHtml = "<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" id=\"result-table-" + tableFor + postFixForTableId + "\" onclick=\"ShowTable(result-table-" + tableFor + postFixForTableId + ")\"> \
     <p align=\"center\">For loop number: " + postFixForTableId + ", <span id=\"stuCnt" + postFixForTableId + "\"> \
     <\/span> student(s) were " + message + "</p></a>";
```

And with jQuery appending this code to a div The code for this is below

```
var node = document.getElementById('node-id');
$('#node-id').append(infoHtml);
```

Now with this i am correcly getting the link with `ShowTable()` function with required parameter

My code for making Show Table Function is

```
function ShowTable(tableId) {
   // blah .. blah
}
```

When i run this The console gives the error `Uncaught Reference Erroe: ShowTable is not defined`

My all code is inside `$(document).ready()` function

Comment: since you are using inlined event handler make sure that the `ShowTable` function is available in the global scope

Comment: did you add the method in a dom ready handler or in any other closure scope

Comment: Why are you initializing a node variable when you are going to use $('#node-id') on the next line?

Comment: @Chandranshu thank for finding that it was a rubbish out there while in development phase

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) for `dynamically added elements` like,

```
 var infoHtml = "<a class="a-showtable" href=\"javascript:void(0);\" id=\"result-table-" + tableFor + postFixForTableId + "\" data-tableFor=" + tableFor + " data-postfix="+postFixForTableId + "\"> \
 <p align=\"center\">For loop number: " + postFixForTableId + ", <span id=\"stuCnt" + postFixForTableId + "\"> \
 <\/span> student(s) were " + message + "</p></a>";
```

And call it like,

```
$(document).on('click','.a-showtable',function(){
   // you code to show table
   // or call it like,
   tableFor=$(this).data('tableFor');
   postfix=$(this).data('postfix');
   ShowTable('result-table-'+tableFor+postfix);        
});
```